# Stripe use different payment method for two customer subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

I am planning on integrating stripe into our application. There is a requirement to add multiple subscriptions for a customer (which looks to be possible with stripe). However, after looking at their API, I can't find a way to set which payment method will be used with each subscription. We want to enable a customer to choose two different methods for each of their subscriptions. Looking at the stripe API docs however, it seems that all subscriptions are billed to the default source on the customer. I can't find any way to specify that a specific subscription be billed to a specific payment method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It is a current limitation of Stripe's API that subscriptions are always billed to the customer's default payment source. If you want to have multiple subscriptions billed to different sources, you'd need to have multiple customer objects, each with a different payment method as its default source, and create the subscriptions on the appropriate customer objects.</strike>

EDIT: The above is no longer true! You can now use different sources for different subscriptions, using the [`default_source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_source) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default_source of your subscription.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object

default_source:

ID of the default payment source for the subscription. It must belong to the customer associated with the subscription and be in a chargeable state. If not set, defaults to the customer’s default source.